# Problems with wpf windows location

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I have an application that runs in a second screen, when the user runs the application in the first screen the application detect the second monitor and change their position to the secondary screen.

This have a problem, the the children of the main window, appear in the first monitor. This should not happen if the owner property is correctly established.

```
Window1 w = new Window1();
win.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
```

My application is complex and is composed by components thats are calling child windows, but I attached a code to illustrate the problem. Execute the code in first monitor, move manually the window to the secondary monitor and press the button to call the child window thats appear in the first monitor :( .

**Note**: I know that I can write a code that detect the secondary monitor in each child window and move to then, but I want a solution more simple and correct, if is possible.

**Note2**: Runs the application outside visual studio, direct from the '.exe'. In Visual studio works fine.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Control="clr-namespace:Borrarrrrr"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Control:UserControl1  x:Name="ctr" />
    </Grid>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Window1 w = new Window1();
        //w.Owner = this;
        w.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        w.Show();
    }
}


<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>

    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 w = new Window1();
            w.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            w.Show();
        }
    }


<Window x:Class="Test.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"
        WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid Background="Aqua">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try setting [Window.WindowStartupLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation.aspx):

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 w = new Window1();
    w.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
    w.WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
    w.Show();
}
```

Comment: in an MDI application, where not only the main window could potentially spawn new windows, it's maybe preferable to use `w.Owner = this;`

Comment: Thanks for the response, obviously this don't work. The centerowner property is already established in the XAML. WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner". I encourage you to play with the code, I think that there are a WPF bug.

Comment: Is there any change to behaviour after setting `WindowStartupLocation` of a child window? Setting this achieves required result for me.

Comment: Not to me. The behaviour is correct executing the application from visual studio. Is also correct when the child window is not set as maximized... But the code attached exactly must be a bad result.